# Why does while(int) end when int = 0?

Tags: c++, boolean, do-while, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to find an input in C++ equivalent to Java's in.hasNextInt and I found this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  int myint;

  std::cout << "Please enter some integers (enter 0 to end):\n";

  do {
    std::cin >> myint;
    myvector.push_back (myint);
  } while (myint);

  std::cout << "myvector stores " << int(myvector.size()) << " numbers.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

But I don't really get why the input loop would stop when the input is 0. It has the `while(myint)` loop which also confuses me since `myint` is an integer and not a boolean. It may work as a boolean when we input something else for `myint` but I think 0 is still qualified as an integer. Can anyone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 6):

The `int` is converted to a `bool` implicitly. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped
>   enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member
>   values become false. All other values become true.

Answer (score 3):

> It may work as a boolean when we input something else for myint but I think 0 is still qualified as an integer.

I think this is where your misunderstanding lays. We can't "input something else for `myint`". It can only ever hold an integer value. If the input stream can't parse an integer, it won't be putting anything into `myint`, it has nothing *to* put.

So you can't be checking that `myint` holds an integer or something else, there is nothing else to hold *except* integers. As such, the only question is how an integer can be tested for truthiness. As you have been told already, integers are convertible to bools. 0 is false, and anything else is true. That is what the loop condition checks. What it can only ever check at all.

Answer (score 3):

Others have already explained why `while(myint)` stops when `myint` is 0, so instead I want to give you an idea of what you can do instead.

First you can look up the [return values on `operator>>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/):

> The extracted value or sequence is not returned, but directly stored in the variable passed as argument.
>   Errors are signaled by modifying the internal state flags

That means that you can use the call `std::cin.good()` to check if anything has gone wrong with your reads. Then the loop stops when you give it an input that isn't an int (or whitespace, `operator>>` ignores that by default).

```
do {
    std::cin >> myint;
    if (std::cin.good())  // Keep the last, failed read from inserting a 0
        myvector.push_back(myint);
} while (std::cin.good());
```

Hopefully this gives you some ideas you can build on.

Answer (score 2):

From the C++ 17 Standard (7.14 Boolean conversions)

> 1 **A prvalue of arithmetic**, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or
>   pointer-to-member type **can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A
>   zero value**, null pointer value, or null member pointer value **is
>   converted to false; any other value is converted to true**. For direct-
>   initialization (11.6), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

And (9 Statements)

> 4. ...The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the 
>      expression, contextually converted to bool for statements other
>      than switch;...

Thus the condition in the do-while statement is equivalent to

```
  do {
    std::cin >> myint;
    myvector.push_back (myint);
  } while ( myint != 0 );
```

If you need to exclude the value `0` from pushing it into the vector then the loop should be rewritten the following way

```
while ( ( std::cin >> myint ) and ( myint != 0 ) )
{
    myvector.push_back( myint );
}
```